# What is the terminology of the waiting period between two successive harvests?

Tags: terminology

I am writing an article and want to simplify the content by avoiding repeating a long sentence to represent a waiting period between 2 consecutive harvests.

What is the terminology of the waiting period between two successive harvests?

Any activities are allowed during the waiting period, whether the plant is growing, or anything else.

Comment: Would you please post an example sentence so we can see the exact context of your request?

Comment: You might simply say, "inter-harvest period" or something to that effect.

Comment: We call that a *year*.

Comment: @zpletan: `inter-harvest period` sounds good and understandable.

Comment: If anything (at all) can happen, why call it 'waiting' period?

Comment: @Kris: Anything sensible activities except for harvesting for sure.   The waiting period should be minimal, not for doing unnecessary activities.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's 'waiting'. If harvest to harvest is 'waiting', then when is 'working'? The Q. is ambiguous -- in fact, misleading.

Comment: @Kris: From my point of view as not a farmer, I need to wait for watching the harvesting event. The period in question is the minimal time interval between two consecutive harvests. During the period, any relevant activities can occur but we don't need to discuss here.

Comment: Nevermind. You've already found your answer.

Comment: @Kris: Feel free to edit my question because I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Forgiver I see accepted "fallow" as the answer but "fallow" does not refer to the normal year between harvests..it is a special use of the land before planting the next crop, but it sounds like you were looking for a word for the normal cycle of plowing, cultivating, etc.

Comment: @JeffSahol: OK. I canceled the acceptance mark and let others to vote the best answer.

Comment: This is like asking "What is the terminology for the waiting period from the end of spring to the start of the next?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will weigh in with the answer that seems correct to me: there is no such word. That is, if you are referring to the period between the end of one harvest and the start of the next, which would include plowing, leaving it to lay for the winter, cultivating, planting, and growing.

Of the alternatives given, *fallow*, *crop rotation*, and *intercropping* are all different concepts already associated with farming. The *growing season* starts after planting, so does not cover the time between harvest and planting, and really refers to the period of time during which crops *may* be grown for a particular climate/environment. While *cycle time* seems to fit ok, it would properly refer to the period from the start of one harvest to the start of the other (and even then, only for a six sigma farmer :)).

Comment: +1. (I was liking this answer anyway, but _six sigma farmer_ really reeled me in.)

Comment: Interesting... *six sigma farmer* turned me off this answer.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer to the question as currently posed. Since OP doesn't want to impose any constraints on what actually happens between one harvest and the next, it could include not only the "growing season" itself, but soil preparation, sowing, fields lying fallow for any amount of time, etc. Not to mention monsoon season/24-hour darkness in some regions, plus delays while the farmer negotiates a loan for more seed corn, etc., etc.

Answer (score 2):

The period between planting and harvest is called the *growing season*.

Comment: Obviously OP is referring to the time from reaping to the next planting, when no growing (or any activity for that matter) takes place.

Comment: @Kris No he clearly says that growing may be taking place.

Comment: Oh that edit came in too late, maybe? In any case, growing is only one of the possibilities -- and for only a part of the period in question, right?

Comment: @Kris Yes, I think there simply isn't a commonly used word for the whole period.

Answer (score 1):

The farmers and ranchers I know refer to the time between crops as ***[fallow](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallow) period***, ***fallow season***, or ***fallow crop***. Between crops farmers will plow the fields and leave them unseeded for a time, usually a few months to a year. This is so that the land can recover the fertility lost, especially following a more hearty crop. This is also likely why there is time between harvests - the land is laying ***fallow***.

Comment: That is the harvest to planting, not harvest to harvest, period.

Comment: @Kris There is not a clear-cut, common use non-archaic word or phrase that indicates the time from harvest-to-harvest. And if there was, most farmers and ranchers wouldn't use it. They might use *growing season(s)* if it's an annual crop. But there are crops, like hay, that can be harvested multiple times in a season. If you want refer to the time between harvests there's not going to be a good word for that because it's not a useful measurement of time. If you're referring to the time between crops, which *is* a useful indicator, you *can* use *fallow period* or some variation thereof.

Comment: This is clearly not the time when "the plant may be growing", right?

Comment: I was the first to answer this question and had *fallow time* as my answer. I deleted my answer, because as @Kris points out the OP added the stipulation (after I answered) that plants could be growing during this time. Farmers definitely do not grow plants in the fallow time.

Comment: @kris "The" plant or "A" plant? A *fallow* field typically has no *cash* crop growing on it. Instead of leaving an arid, dry field of dirt the rancher/farmer may seed a zero profit field of clover during a fallow season - a useful tactic to avoid soil erosion. The land is still in a rejuvenating fallow stage but there's nothing growing that will make him money. Without further clarification from OP I still like *fallow* to describe the time between crops because there is no good, useful word or phrase for the time from harvest-to-harvest.

Comment: @JLG The edit has only further confounded the confusion. Now the post as it stands is a mess. See also, my comments above at the OP.

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy: I had quoted the OP: "the plant".

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy: I think what you're describing is what is known as a *cover crop*.

Comment: Clover (or more often, legumes/beans) are often grown on a fallow field even if only to be ploughed in - their role is to "fix" nitrogen into the soil for use by future cash crops.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yep, I know...I'm an Iowa girl. Farmers still call it a cover crop. http://www.uvm.edu/vtvegandberry/factsheets/covercrops.html

Comment: @JLG: Ah right - I was basically just regurgitating what they taught me in school *many* moons ago about crop rotation, but now you come to mention it, I seem to recal that soil erosion has been something of an issue in Iowa over recent years. In which case I suppose "cover crop" is partly/mainly intended to hang on to the topspoil so it doesn't blow or get washed away.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there must be a proper term, but I might loosely call it the ***intercrop (-period)***.

I know, this is also used in the sense of a minor crop between two main crops. You therefore, can add the '-period' suffix to clarify.

[Edit-1] per Op's Edit-1:
The period from one harvest to the next is probably called a ***season*** in plain language.

Comment: Intercrop already means something entirely different.

Comment: @z7sg which is already stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose multiple crops are grown on the same field, **crop rotation period** [describes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_rotation) the inter-harvest time adequately.

But if only the same crop is grown every year, there is no crop rotation, so a **year** is the inter-harvest time. In this case I do not understand why you need a separate word.

Comment: Because we need a single term for both cases, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

*Cycle time* will work, particularly if you parenthetically or appositively define it; for example, for 
[rice](http://r0.unctad.org/infocomm/anglais/rice/crop.htm) one might write:

> In tropical climates, the cycle time (from harvest to harvest) is often six months, or in Vietnam and the Mekong Delta, four months.

Comment: Or maybe say _harvest cycle_?

Answer (score 0):

I believe he is talking about the period between one harvest and the next.  For example:  sugarcane crops for the production of sugar or ethanol.  After the harvest period (twice a year in Brazil) there is a gap in the production of ethanol when prices normally rise.  It is called in this case, the "off season", although some refer to it as inter-harvest period.

Comment: Hi Cesar, welcome to ELU!  "off-season" and "inter-harvest period" are great answers in my opinion.  As you seem to be speaking from experience, do you know of any references available online that corroborate these phrases?